# Rifidi Emulator 1.6 is not working

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am working with **Rifidi** Emulator in Linux, i have followed the installation steps and finally when i run ./emulator it is starting and immediately its get stopped the command is as follows

```
`    administrator@admin:~/RifidiEmulator-1.6$ ./emulator 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/administrator/RifidiEmulator-1.6/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520/eclipse_1206.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now. 
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'. 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.alien 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.awid 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.epc 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.llrp 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.sirit local 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.symbol 
Registered org.rifidi.emulator.reader.thingmagic 
Starting org.rifidi.ui.ide 
Stopping org.rifidi.ui.ide 
Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.llrp 
Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.alien 
Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.awid `
Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.epc`
`Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.sirit`
`Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.symbol` 
`Shutting down org.rifidi.emulator.reader.thingmagic`
```

Its get immediately shutting down so the emulator is not starting up

Answer (score 0):

Had that same problem and it was fixed by using the 32 bit version of the JDK. Just make sure you set it as the default jdk on your machine (here I had to use the alternatives script to do that).

I'm not sure if the exact version matters, but I'm using Java version <del>1.8.0_91</del> 1.7.0_79.

edit: Some features don't work on Java 8.